# How can I prevent an antivirus software form uninstalling wine applications?

Tags: wine, antivirus

I have a couple of Windows applications installed through Wine and these are running quite well. The trouble, however, is that every time I run the anti-virus programme ClamTk, it uninstalls the Wine applications and I have to install them all over again. The only way I can avoid this is to individually exempt the files related to the Wine applications from quarantine, which is obviously a bother. So my questions are:

1. Can I configure ClamTk in such a way that it will automatically exempt the above-mentioned files? And if this is not possible with ClamTk, is there any other ant-virus program with which it can be done?
2. If the Wine applications are thus exempted, will it make the system vulnerable to malwares and viruses?

Comment: I think you better check why ClamAV considers the software to be offensive. It might be a 'false positive' - but then; what if it is not?

Comment: Exemptions in your AV software will always cause a vulnarability in your computer... Even if your software is clean, if it ever gets infected with malware/virus, your virus scanner will skip over it and not detect any problems. The best way is to find a solution with ClamAV. There are a bunch of free online AV scanners which you can submit your files to to double-check as well.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, av software is usually not all that necessary so long as you don't install programs all that often outside of the official repos and use a sandboxed browser such as chrome. If you desperately need to remove a virus, or want something on hand, really just use something like malwarebytes boot disk or something, otherwise it is mostly unnecessary to run it and will mainly just cause errors and system lag.